# Error [603] when trying to use a custom Function/Procedure in Snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, procedure

I am trying to use a custom function/procedure in Snowflake. I created the function/procedure with no issues. I can query it if I use one specific date, but not when I am trying to use a date field from a table.

Function/Procedure:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION xxx.ADDWORKDAYS ( START_DATE DATE , DAYS NUMBER(5,0))
RETURNS DATE
LANGUAGE SQL
AS
$$ 

SELECT DT
FROM

(SELECT DT
    ,  DN
    ,  ROW_NUMBER () OVER (ORDER BY 1) RN
FROM
(
SELECT DATEADD(DAY, RN, START_DATE) DT
       ,DAYNAME(DATEADD(DAY, RN, START_DATE)) DN
, RN
FROM
(SELECT ROW_NUMBER () OVER (ORDER BY 1) RN
  FROM TABLE(GENERATOR(ROWCOUNT => 5)) v 
  )
)  b
WHERE DN NOT IN ('Sat','Sun')
AND NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM xxxx.HOLIDAYS A
               where A.FULL_DATE = B.DT
               )

) 
WHERE RN <= DAYS
$$ 
;
```

Query:

```
SELECT
    D.FULL_DATE
  , xxxx.ADDWORKDAYS(D.FULL_DATE, 1) AS WORKDAYS_1    


FROM xxxx.DATE_TABLE D
```

Error Message:
SQL Error [603] [XX000]: SQL execution internal error:
Processing aborted due to error 300002:834137686; incident 5537161.
SQL execution internal error:
Processing aborted due to error 300002:834137686; incident 5537161.
SQL execution internal error:
Processing aborted due to error 300002:834137686; incident 5537161.

I expect it to give me the next workday from the full date field in the date_table. I can get a result if I query it like this:

```
SELECT XXXX.ADDWORKDAYS('2023-05-26', 1)
```

Comment: What’s the datatype for D.FULL_DATE?

Comment: @NickW - It is DATE.

Comment: You might want to contact Snowflake support with the error and incident details.  They can look up the reason on the backend.